# Importing python DirectX into c++ DirectX program

Tags: c++, directx, python

I'm not asking for code or anything, just some advice on what to google, because I have no idea what to call this process.

I made a video player (with full controls) with python and DirectX and would like to just simply import the rendering of the display into a c++ DirectX fullscreen app. That way, it can be customizable to the user.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of Python-C++ bindings.

There's a few options:

- [The raw Python API (in C)](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html)
- [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/) (probably the
  easiest to use)